# Dynamic role names in Java EE Security

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I want my users to define role names and which functions they are authorized to perform. How can this be achieved without hardcoding names in annotations?

```
@RolesAllowed(value = "SomeRole”)
```

For example if there are 3 functions in the system F1, F2 and F3 I want the user to define a role name and assign authorized functions.

Comment: How can that be secure?  Sounds like I could give myself admin access.

Comment: No, you can’t update anything you are not authorized, including your own credentials

Comment: Is there a fixed number of functions that users may be allowed to perform?

Comment: No, admins can authorize any number of functions to roles